# Is it possible to edit data table values and then save it with new one in R shiny

Tags: r

I created a form on R shiny which basically renders mtcars dataset with editable=TRUE.So now when i run my application i am able edit mtcars dataset but not able to save it.
Can anyone help me with this like edit the dataset then save it and then render updated value into dataset it should not loose on page refresh.

Comment: To save the data I would write to a file. To load the saved changes read from that file instead of using the default mtcars variable.

Comment: Michael i understood your point but my concern is something else i have created a dataset like mtcars and i am rendering it on shiny as datatable with editable.Now i want to save the editable dataset with new value.

Comment: if i remember correctly thats only possible with `rhandsontable`. You should find similar questions adressing this issue,..

Comment: BigDataScientist-i tried rhandsontable but its not working for me.Apart from that i came across shinyforms packages to create shinyform and then easily save data from text but i am not able to find "shinyforms" packages in R.So can you help me on this,can you suggest me some alternative packages to achieve the same?

Comment: I figured it out.
Thank you all for putting efforts and comments. :)